# Change style of input box without default white box

Tags: css, styling, inputbox

I am having trouble changing the style of my input box. I want to have the accordion style as the actual input itself but the white basic input box is still there.

The class for the accordion is "card" but when I add it to the input it doesn't work.

```css
.card {
  background-color: var(--background);
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 90px;
  border: 3px solid var(--primary);
  padding: 15px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 30px) auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 -3px var(--background), 0 0 0 0px #1FC11B, /* Green */
  0 0 0 -3px var(--background), 0 0 0 0px #FFD913, /* Yellow */
  0 0 0 -3px var(--background), 0 0 0 0px #FF9C55, /* Orange */
  0 0 0 -3px var(--background), 0 0 0 0px #FF5555/* Red */
  ;
  transition: box-shadow 1s, top 1s, left 1s;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px #1FC11B, /* 
    Green */
  20px -20px 0 -3px var(--background), 20px -20px #FFD913, /* Yellow */
  30px -30px 0 -3px var(--background), 30px -30px #FF9C55, /* Orange */
  40px -40px 0 -3px var(--background), 40px -40px #FF5555;
  /* Red */
}

 :root {
  --primary: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --secondary: #22D2A0;
  --background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card p {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Archivo Black", "Archivo", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<form name="login">
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="card" placeholder="userid" name="userid" onchange="javascript:this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="check(this.form)" /> <br>
    <P>&nbsp</P>
</form>
```

I want the input box itself to be the accordion box I have styled above.

Comment: Where is the css `card` class? What CSS property is not applied of that class? How the desired output should look like?

Comment: Edited as you wanted